# Loop to add Components to JPanel

Tags: java, arraylist, jpanel

I need to create a loop to go through firstResults and latestResults and add the 'i-th' component of each to my _resultsPanel JPanel, however I am not sure how to make a proper loop for this.

```
public void displayResults(Practice pr) {
    _resultsPanel.removeAll();
    ArrayList<TestResult> firstResults = pr.firstResults();
    ArrayList<TestResult> latestResults = pr.latestResults();

    // this is my attempt at the loop 

for( int i = 0; i < pr.firstResults().size() && i< pr.latestResults().size();i++){
        firstResults.get(i);
        latestResults.get(i);
            System.out.println(i);


        // TODO Choose an appropriate loop to go through both firstResults and latestResults and add the i-th component of each to the results panel
    }
```

Comment: What type is `_resultsPanel`? What exactly should be added to it?

Comment: _resultsPanel is a JPanel, and I need to add the index of each ArrayList.

Comment: Did need the results intertwined (so your Mohave component from firstResults then latestResults)? Or are the combined into a single component? Or can your have all the components for firstResult followed by the components for latestResults? Are the lists the same size? Do your need all the values from both list?

Comment: I can't help but think that JTable would be a better solution